# How can I call a function specified in a GET param?

Tags: php, function

I have a simple link like so: `<a href="?wp_accept_function=10">Accept</a>`

The idea is that this will run a function called wp_accept_function and pass in the id of 10 how do I do this? Thanks

Here is the code I have so far, but I feel I'm going wrong and need to pass the number into the function and then be able to use it within the function. Thanks

```
if ( isset ( $_GET ['wp_accept_function'] ) )
        {
            function wp_accept_favor ( $id )
            {

                // JAZZ

            }           
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want this:

First you need to define the function.

```
function wp_accept_favor($id) {
   // do something
}
```

Then, you have to check if the parameter is set and call the function.

```
if (isset($_GET['wp_accept_function'])) {
    // call the function passing the id casted to an integer
    wp_accept_favor((int)$_GET['wp_accept_function']);               
}
```

The cast to `(int)` is for avoid passing a non-integer type for `wp_accept_favor()` function, but you can handle it as you want.

Comment: Tried that but the function isn't getting called when the ?wp_accept_favor is being added to the url. Tested with a simple echo and no dice?

Comment: Just noticed you changed favor to function in the GET

Comment: But the string to be added to the url is `?wp_accept_function=something` not ?`wp_accept_favor=something`. `wp_accept_favor` is just the function name.

Comment: @Cameron: Is what you wrote at your question on if clause and at your link... (`<a href="?wp_accept_function=10">Accept</a>`).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to build something generic...

```
// Add a white list of functions here which can be called via GET.
$safeFunctions = array('wp_accept_function');

foreach($_GET as $function => $argument) {
    if (in_array($function, $safeFunctions)
        AND function_exists($function)) {    

        $function($argument);

    }
}
```

However, make sure you have a whitelist of safe functions, otherwise your app will no doubt have security issues.

Comment: Seems a bit silly to give an answer that is inherently insecure.

Comment: @jnpcl It will be secure with the whitelist of allowed functions.

Comment: @alex: Whitelist wasn't in place when I first looked. :) Plus, the OP has a pretty specific scenario, so I don't think your answer is good for him.

Comment: Besides there obviously being something better to iterate than `$_GET`, can someone point out the problem and/or security issue here?

Comment: @jnpcl It may be useful to future people stumbling across this question wondering how to call a function using a GET param.

Comment: @Murilo Vasconcelos Thank you :)

Comment: @alex: Edit your answer again so I can fix my vote. As for any 'problem', the OP doesn't need a catch-all to pass function names via `$_GET`, so the answer is beyond the scope of his question.